# Scala Akka not loading Configuration file with -Dconfig.file option

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, configuration, akka

I created simple application using scala,akka,maven with Intellij Idea and I created fat jar of my application, I tried to run jar with below command

java -jar bac-pqr.jar -Dconfig.file=/home/pqr-xvcx-xcvxv-sdf/application.conf -Dconfig.trace=loads

I am getting below error while running the jar through command prompt:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'bac-pqr'
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:152)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:145)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:172)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:184)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:246)
        at .config.Settings$.Name$lzycompute(Settings.scala:37)
        at .config.Settings$.ClusterName(Settings.scala:37)
        at Main$.main(Main.scala:76)
        at .Main.main(Main.scala)
```

I don't know even after providing configuration file why Its throwing such exception.Please find below my complete application.conf file:

```
bac-pqr {
  kafka {
    bac-pqr-topic = [${?bac-pqr_TOPIC}, "Test"]
    failover-dlq-topic = [${?FAILOVER_DLQ_TOPIC}, "Test.dlq"]
    workflow-topic = [${?WORKFLOW_TOPIC}, "Test.workflow"]
    producer {
      hostname = [${?KAFKA_HOST}, "localhost"]
      port = [${?KAFKA_PORT}, 9092]
    }
    consumer {
      hostname = [${?HOST}, "localhost"]
      port = [${?PORT}, 9092]
      groupid = [${?GROUP_ID}, "test-consumer"]
      auto-offset-reset = "earliest"
    }
    offset {
      group-batch = 10
      group-time = 5
      parallelism-factor = 3
    }
  }
  akka {
    actor {
      cluster-name = "ABCSystem"
      timeout = [${?AKKA_ACTOR_TIMEOUT}, 10]
      supervisor-strategy {
        max-number-of-retries = 10
        within-time-range = 30
      }
    }
  }
  elastic-search {
    hostname = [${?SEARCH_HOSTNAME}, "localhost"]
    port = [${?SEARCH_PORT}, 9300]
    index = [${?SEARCH_INDEX}, "test_index"]
    type = [${?SEARCH_DOC_TYPE}, "portfolio"]
  }
  shutdown-hook-time = 30
}

akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    deployment {
      /ABCActor {
        router = round-robin-pool
        nr-of-instances = 20
      }
    }
  }
  kafka {
    consumer {
      poll-interval = 50ms
      poll-timeout = 50ms
      stop-timeout = 30s
      close-timeout = 20s
      commit-timeout = 15s
      wakeup-timeout = 10s
      use-dispatcher = "akka.kafka.default-dispatcher"
      kafka-clients {
        enable.auto.commit = true //Fix me
      }
    }
  }
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2551
    }
  }
  cluster {
    seed-host = "127.0.0.1"
    seed-host = ${?SEED_HOST}
    seed-port = "2551"
    seed-port = ${?AKKA_CLUSTER_SEED_PORT}
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://"${bac-pqr.akka.actor.cluster-name}"@"${akka.cluster.seed-host}":"${akka.cluster.seed-port}
    ]
    min-nr-of-members = 1
    auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s //Look out before finish
  }
}
akka.cluster.metrics.enabled=off
akka.extensions=["akka.cluster.metrics.ClusterMetricsExtension"]
circuit-breaker {
  maxFailures = [${?CBREAKER_MAX_FAILURES}, 10]
  callTimeout = [${?CBREAKER_MAX_FAILURES}, 10000]
  resetTimeout = [${?CBREAKER_MAX_FAILURES}, 30000]
}``
```

I am not having any conf file in my fat jar. I want to provide conf file to jar externally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the order of your arguments. Arguments after `-jar file.jar` are for you programs main method not the jvm.

```
 java -Dconfig.file=/home/hdp66-ss-mods-uk/AEM-Sprint0/ResourceBundle.old/lib/application.conf -Dconfig.trace=loads -jar exception-management.jar
```